# How do I reduce the rmse while performing multiple linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, decision-tree, lasso-regression

So I have a dataset which has 84 rows and 18 predictors. I need to predict Annual_salary based on the data provided.
[image]

I did create a model after changing all the categorical variables to factors.
Then I used olsrr package to get best subset and got it to be around 7 predictors.
Using those predictors I created a model to get rmse around 240,000.

How can I reduce this rmse? I'm certainally new to R programming and need some help.
What are the steps I should go about with this data and in what order?

What are some of the other models(algorithms) that I can use to predict?
I have used lasso/ridge and Multiple linear regression and I've got lowest rmse using MLR. I might have not implemented any of these correctly so I don't really know if the previous statement is valid.

Link to the data : [GDrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Imp3po9CcKdiuTp7ii3-i9VduoJsSAuM?usp=sharing)

Comment: This question is more appropriate for crossvalidated website instead of here. Have you tried doing log-transformation of your independent variables? does it change the RMSE?

Comment: How can we help you know if your models are correctly implemented if you neither give us all you data nor share the code you used to fit them?  Whilst this question is better suited to stats.stackexchange, I believe OP has not provided sufficient information for the question to be answered there. Therefore voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: Hey @Limey I've added the dataset link above.

Comment: @Eva last I tried was using Random Forests regressor. I got the rmse around 106k. I used ntree=3 so, does having less ntree cause overfitting? And no I haven't tried log tranformation of the Ivs yet